# How use greencoding in Next Js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Please help me with step wise details of using green coding in next js.

I have gone through eco-code plugin of git-hub, how we can use it with our project.

https://github.com/green-code-initiative/ecoCode/tree/main/ecocode-rules-specifications/src/main/rules/EC9

for reference i have added the above link, I tried to search for similar NPMs but was not able to succeed.

Comment: What specific issue are you having? Isn't it linting rules?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to implement green coding into next js project to maintain the standards and rules of coding how we can achieve it..?